# Connexion to MSAccess with ODBC/JDBC works on Eclipse not on release

Tags: java, database, eclipse, ms-access, odbc

i am using a jdbc-odbc connexion to read an Access database.
All is working with Eclipse, but with my release .jar i've "Source de données introuvable et nom de pilote non spécifié" ("Data source name not found and no default driver specified").
I included the rt.jar (driver), the manifest etc.
Do you have any idea?

```
public class SQL {
    public String url = "d:/neg_p/MonBureau/AccessToWeb/pfsce.mdb";
    public Connection connection = null;

    //variables pour JDBC
    private String urljdbc = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ="+url+";"; // format spécifique à Access
    private String login = "";
    private String password = "";

    public boolean Connect()
    {
        try
        {
            // connexion
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            File f = new File(url);
            if (!f.exists())
                System.out.println("Fichier non trouvé.");
            this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(urljdbc,login,password);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Erreur lors de la connexion à la base de données : "+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The anwser is : the jar must be launched with java 32bits.

On win7 64 you must uninstall java64.
If the command java does not exist (cmd), you must set the environment variable "path" to the jdk or the jre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anwser is : the jar must be launched with java 32bits.

On win7 64 you must uninstall java64.
If the command java does not exist (cmd), you must set the environment variable "path" to the jdk or the jre.